# Android Studio: Add .cpp file tree without building

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to add a tree of .h/.cpp files to the Android Studio editor for reference - so that they can be edited but not actually built/compiled by Android Studio?

I have JNI/NDK files which I want to build manually from the command line but I don't want Gradle/Android Studio to build these files.

There is a Gradle 'exclude' command/function which may be what I need but I cannot get it to work.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        exclude 'jni'
        //exclude ("jni/**")
        //jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to figure this out with a vanilla Android Studio set-up but by using the Gradle Experimental Plugin I have ended up with the desired outcome. Once I got the 0.7.0 experimental plugin working (and my build.gradle configured for the new 'model' scoping), I was able to remove the sourceSets statement, successfull sync, edit within Android Studio and build from the command line via ndk-build.